# Java Vertx unable to provide user id password for my post request using webClient

Tags: java, vert.x

I am new to Java and Vert.x
I am Using vertx 3.5.3 
I am trying to implement basic Authentication so that i can log into the remote sever before sending the post request
I tried the below code which is giving a compiler error .
I am getting a compiler error .

The method basicAuthentication(String, String) is undefined for the type HttpRequest What am i doing wrong .

The requirement is that i need to send user id and password for the remote server and access end point with a post request using a json Post body using Vert.x web client

I tried the below code

```
package com.aexp.csrt.qs.cb.resources;
import com.aexp.csrt.qs.models.cb.passTrou.SourceQueryModel;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClientOptions;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.HttpResponse;
import io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer;

public class QueryExecutorFTS implements QueryExecutor {
    private WebClient webClient;

    @Override
    public void executeQuery(SourceQueryModel Qm, RoutingContext rc) {

        WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions().setMaxPoolSize(10).setConnectTimeout(5000)
                .setVerifyHost(false);

        JsonObject jreq = new JsonObject(Qm.getSourceQuery().getSourceDsl().getQuery());

        Vertx vertx = rc.vertx();
        webClient = WebClient.create(vertx.getDelegate(), options);

         webClient
         .basicAuthentication("myid", "mypassword")
        .post(8094, "lpdospdb51079.phx.aexp.com", "/api/index/Text_search_name_idx/query")
        .sendJsonObject(jreq,
                ar -> {
                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                        HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
                        rc.response().setStatusCode(200).end(response.bodyAsString());
                    } else {
                        ar.cause().printStackTrace();
                        rc
                              .response()
                              .setStatusCode(500)
                              .setStatusMessage(ar.cause().getMessage())
                              .end();
                    }
                })
        ;


    }

}
```

Comment: `WebClient`has no method of `basicAuthentication`, you can send password though heads

Comment: Any Example You can share will be helpful and will be appreciated

Comment: did you wtire the server code too? what auth are you using on the server side? you might need to first POST a usr/pass and get a token back, then add the token to the next request as cookie. check the handling sessions https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/js/#_handling_sessions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you using the session handler on the server side like so:

```
    router.route().handler(CookieHandler.create());
    router.route().handler(SessionHandler.create(LocalSessionStore.create(vertx)));
    router.route().handler(UserSessionHandler.create(authProvider));
```

you now need to first authenticate your client with the url you defined for login.

your login path -> /login

```
    router.route(HttpMethod.POST, path)
        .handler(FormLoginHandler.create(authProvider));
```

you normally POST the user / pass JSON

now on the client side you need two steps

1. POST your cred to the login URL

   ```
   MultiMap form = MultiMap.caseInsensitiveMultiMap();
   form.add("username", user);
   form.add("password", password);

   client
       .post(port, "localhost", "/login")
       .putHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
       .sendForm(form, ar -> {
           if (ar.succeeded()) {
               log.info("RESOURCES: {}", ar.result().bodyAsString());
               log.info("COOKIES: {}", ar.result().cookies());//.getHeader("vertx-web.session"));
               ar.result().cookies().stream().filter(c -> c.startsWith("vertx-web.session")).findFirst().ifPresent(s -> {
                   // do something with the session cookie - >cookie.accept(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(";")));
               });
           } else {
               log.error("Something went wrong", ar.cause());
           }
       });
   ```
2. once you have the cookie you can call the server again.

   ```
       client.
           .get(port, "localhost", "/resource")
           .putHeader("Cookie", cookie)
           .send(ar -> { ...
   ```